# XSL - combination following-sibling in an for each loop

Tags: xml, xslt, for-loop

good morning ! I have only a small problem. I have an XML structure, here is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div type="letter">
        <head>
          <persName type="creator">
            <forename>Theo</forename>
            <surname>Barnes</surname>
          </persName>
          <persName type="addressee">
            <forename>Alex</forename>
            <surname>Rollett</surname>
          </persName>
        </head>
        <opener>
          <dateline>
            <date when="2015-01">2015-01</date>
            <placeName key="Graz">Graz</placeName>
          </dateline>
          <salute>Hello everybody</salute>
        </opener> 
</div>
```

And here is my XSL Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
        <div>
          <head>
                 <xsl:for-each select="//persName[@type='creator']">
                 <xsl:text> From </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="forename"/>
                        <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::persName[1]/forename"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:text> at  </xsl:text>
                    <!--  her is the error, i think but why-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="dateline[1]/date"/>   
                 </xsl:for-each>
           </head>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have the problem, that i am not able to add the value of the dateline or the placeName it does not matter. Id should also work in a loop, because the reason is this is only a short snip of the document. So my question is where is my mistake. I have commmented the problem point in the code.
At the moment the output is:

```
From Theo to Alex at
```

I expect or better i am searching for the following output:

```
From Theo to Alex at 2015-01 location Graz
```

All the best and read from you soon.
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context element in the following part is `persName`, since it is inside foreach loop where you're looping through `persName` :

```
<xsl:value-of select="dateline[1]/date"/>
```

This is one possible XPath expression to get the target `date` element from the context `persName` :

```
<xsl:value-of select="following::opener/dateline[1]/date"/>
```

Comment: thank you for the axe expression, this is also working. it is always the way on navigate to the xml expression or ? have a good time cheers ch

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have found the right place of your mistake. The problem is that the `<xsl:value-of select=""/>` instruction does correctly retrieve the desired data because it the for-each you are contextually on a `<persName>` node.

With such a fix you will get what you want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../opener/dateline[1]/date"/>
```

and similarly for the location information:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../opener/dateline[1]/placeName"/>
```

Comment: thank you for the fix, this is working now, but i think is only working on my specific structure..  thank you for the tipp. is there a good tutorial except W3school or is this the wrong place to ask